# Javafx Nullpointerexception using print api

Tags: java, javafx

I've been following this guide https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-print-api/ on making a print setup dialog after pressing a button and printing whatever is inside the text area, I've been getting Nullpointerexception whenever I press it 
it points at

```
boolean proceed = job.showPrintDialog(owner);
```

and

```
pageSetup(Transcript, window);
```

Here's the code:

```
public void AddRecord(ActionEvent event){
    Transcript.setText("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Student Records");
}
private void pageSetup(Node node, Stage owner){
    // Create the PrinterJob
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    if (job == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Show the print setup dialog
    boolean proceed = job.showPrintDialog(owner);

    if (proceed)
    {
        print(job, node);
    }
}
private void print(PrinterJob job, Node node){
    //set status message
    jobStatus.textProperty().bind(job.jobStatusProperty().asString());

    //Print node
    boolean printed = job.printPage(node);
    if (printed){
        job.endJob();
    }

}
public void printText (ActionEvent event){
        Stage window = new Stage();
        pageSetup(Transcript, window);
    }
```

Comment: Pass either `null` or the stage you receive the event (`((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()`) from, not some "placeholder Stage".

Comment: So it worked now, the printer setup dialogue shows up, but theres another error 
Which is whenever I insert a textfield variable for example `Transcript.appendText(Firstname.getText());` it does a NullPointerException

Comment: [mcve] please ... and stick to java naming conventions to improve readability of your code :)